How to use Drogon framework to handle switch databases in case of Database Failover?
I am using C++ Drogon framework for developing Restful microservice.
In case to manage Database Failover mechanism for High Availability purpose, we have to configure Drogon to switch automatically from Primary DBMS to Secondary DBMS in case of Failover and to return to Primary when it is restored.
Setting both DBMS in configuration file, only allow us to create some DbClient exchanging with the targeted database. So, if we have to code manually the switching, we have to catch exception for each query and switch to secondary database client if the exception means that we lost the Primary DBMS.
This kind of management is really bad for quality of code and it is huge effort for nothing because our goal in this case is not writing intentionally one of them but write to the primary always until we lost it as failover works.
One solution was to put load balancer between Drogon and DBMSs but this involve adding new component and monitoring it and it is not our goal.
So, is there any ready mechanism to handle this obvious use case like in Java Spring or other (which ask you just to put the primary and secondary and handle the failover automatically)?
Thx!
